# Eclipse doesn't open because of javaw.exe Path error

Tags: javaw

While trying to run Eclipse, i get an error saying the javaw.exe is not found in the current path. I tried changing the path using configuration.ini file but doesn't work. Also tried reinstalling JDK and setting the PATH environment, it was of no use. Can anyone guide me with it.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @ZaheerKhorajiya windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Put these lines at the end of eclipse.ini

```
-vm
<your path to jdk|jre>/bin/javaw.exe
```

And set the JAVA_HOME environment variable  [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will try and post a comment if it works.